# Not recieving BIND_INPUT_METHOD while making Android IME

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, ime

I am having problems with IME for Android os. I am trying to recieve BIND_INPUT_METHOD permission, but it keep saying this is system-app only =\ An opensource example (DotDashKeyboard) recieves it with no probles, so this is odd. 
Here is my .manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.neothefox.romashka"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service 
        android:name="RomashkaIME"
            android:label="RomashkaIME"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" >

            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got it - I should been just ask for this permission once in service declaration. Now it all up and running, but I still cant figure out how another keyboard work. Id doesn't matter anymore, thou.